# What is the difference between different fadein/fadeout curves in ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audacity

Here is the list of possible curves for `afade` and `acrossfade` filters from here https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#afade-1

```
tri
    select triangular, linear slope (default) 

qsin
    select quarter of sine wave 

hsin
    select half of sine wave 

esin
    select exponential sine wave 

log
    select logarithmic 

ipar
    select inverted parabola 

qua
    select quadratic 

cub
    select cubic 

squ
    select square root 

cbr
    select cubic root 

par
    select parabola 

exp
    select exponential 

iqsin
    select inverted quarter of sine wave 

ihsin
    select inverted half of sine wave 

dese
    select double-exponential seat 

desi
    select double-exponential sigmoid
```

Here is the code for them, from `libavfilter/af_afade.c`:

```
switch (curve) {
case QSIN:
    gain = sin(gain * M_PI / 2.0);
    break;
case IQSIN:
    /* 0.6... = 2 / M_PI */
    gain = 0.6366197723675814 * asin(gain);
    break;
case ESIN:
    gain = 1.0 - cos(M_PI / 4.0 * (CUBE(2.0*gain - 1) + 1));
    break;
case HSIN:
    gain = (1.0 - cos(gain * M_PI)) / 2.0;
    break;
case IHSIN:
    /* 0.3... = 1 / M_PI */
    gain = 0.3183098861837907 * acos(1 - 2 * gain);
    break;
case EXP:
    /* -11.5... = 5*ln(0.1) */
    gain = exp(-11.512925464970227 * (1 - gain));
    break;
case LOG:
    gain = av_clipd(1 + 0.2 * log10(gain), 0, 1.0);
    break;
case PAR:
    gain = 1 - sqrt(1 - gain);
    break;
case IPAR:
    gain = (1 - (1 - gain) * (1 - gain));
    break;
case QUA:
    gain *= gain;
    break;
case CUB:
    gain = CUBE(gain);
    break;
case SQU:
    gain = sqrt(gain);
    break;
case CBR:
    gain = cbrt(gain);
    break;
case DESE:
    gain = gain <= 0.5 ? cbrt(2 * gain) / 2: 1 - cbrt(2 * (1 - gain)) / 2;
    break;
case DESI:
    gain = gain <= 0.5 ? CUBE(2 * gain) / 2: 1 - CUBE(2 * (1 - gain)) / 2;
    break;
}
```

How do they look like? How do they sound like? Which one is recommended for fadein+fadeout and crossfade? Personally I'm just trying to avoid audio clicks, maybe crossfade is a bit of an overkill here.

Related link: http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/fade_and_crossfade.html . Not sure how audacity names translate into ffmpeg names though.

Answer (score 1):

You can find plots for all of the different fade curves here:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AfadeCurves